# Проверка двух объектов на идентичность

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть задача по JavaScript

Нужно полностью сравнить два объекта на идентичность их свойств. Порядок свойств в объекте не важен. Если значением какого-то свойства объекта является массив или объект, то начать сверять и их у обоих объектов.

Объект в свойстве другого объекта нужно сверять рекурсивно.

При сверке объектов - последовательность свойств не важна, но при сверке массивов, важна последовательность элементов, то есть массивы: `[1,2,3,4]` и `[2,1,3,4]` не равны, так как, хотя и имеют одинаковые значения, отличаются в последовательности этих значений.

Полного сравнения объектов я смог добиться, но если в свойстве объекта массив, то каким бы он не был всегда возвращается true. Свойства сравнивал через valueOf для того случая, если свойством будет дата, что бы она сравнивалась корректно.

```
function deepEqual (obj1, obj2){

if(obj1 === obj2){
     return true;
 }
 else{
     if(Object.keys(obj1).length != Object.keys(obj2).length){ // Проверка на одинаковое количество свойств
         return false;
     }
     for(var propName in obj1){

         if (! obj2.hasOwnProperty(propName)) { // Есть ли свойства в обоих объектах
             return false;
         }
         if(obj1[propName].valueOf() !== obj2[propName].valueOf()){ // Одинаковы ли значения свойст 
             if(! deepEqual(obj1[propName], obj2[propName]) ){ // проверка объекта в объекте
                 return false;
             }

        }
     }
 } 
 return true; }
```

Вот данные для проверки

Первый объект

```
 var objA = {
prop1: 'value1',
prop2: 'value2',
prop3: 'value3',
prop4: {
    subProp1: 'sub value1',
    subProp2: {
        subSubProp1: 'sub sub value1',
        subSubProp2: [1, 2, {prop2: 1, prop: 2}, 4, 5]
    }
},
prop5: 1000,
prop6: new Date(2016, 2, 10) };
```

Второй объект

```
 var objB = {
prop5: 1000,
prop3: 'value3',
prop1: 'value1',
prop2: 'value2',
prop6: new Date('2016/03/10'),
prop4: {
    subProp2: {
        subSubProp1: 'sub sub value1',
        subSubProp2: [1, 2, {prop2: 1, prop: 2}, 4, 5]
    },
    subProp1: 'sub value1'
}  };
```

В чем ошибка? Нужно ли для проверки массивов создавать новую функцию?

Comment: Легче всего сравнивать строки, поэтому я в своих проектах просто использую JSON.stringify() и уже получившиеся строки сравниваю

Comment: @Masiama дешево и сердито

Answer (score 6):

сверить 2 объекта можно одной строчкой:

```
function deepEqual (obj1, obj2){
   return JSON.stringify(obj1)===JSON.stringify(obj2);
}
```

Comment: Первый ответ не очень хорош, т.к. для если объекты одинаковы, но разная очередность ключей = будет ошибка.

Comment: @АнастасияЯцура сорты можно вкинуть, при желании

Comment: эти объекты не будут идентичны так как поля в разном прядке даже если дату сделать одинаковыми

Answer (score 5):

[не решение, но хороший пример, как правильно и нужно делать](https://gist.github.com/nicbell/6081098#file-object-compare-js)!

```
Object.compare = function (obj1, obj2) {
  // Цикл через свойства объекта obj1
  for (var p in obj1) {
    //Проверка на то, что оба объекта существуют
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(p) !== obj2.hasOwnProperty(p)) return false;

    switch (typeof (obj1[p])) {
      // Глубокое сравнение объектов по ключам и значения:
      case 'object':
        //Нужно добавить что бы была еще проверка на дату внутри 
        if (
          obj1[p] instanceof Date &&
          obj2[p] instanceof Date &&
          String(obj1[p]) !== String(obj2[p])
        )
          return false
        if (!Object.compare(obj1[p], obj2[p])) return false;
        break;
      // Сравнение данных типа function:
      case 'function':
        if (typeof (obj2[p]) == 'undefined' || (p != 'compare' && obj1[p].toString() != obj2[p].toString())) return false;
        break;
      // Сравнение значений:
      default:
        if (obj1[p] != obj2[p]) return false;
    }
  }

  // Проверка объекта obj2 на дополнительные свойства:
  for (var p in obj2) {
    if (typeof (obj1[p]) == 'undefined') return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Объясните код на русском языке. Если это не Ваш код, то укажите источник.

Comment: Вроде не сложно.
Для каждого свойства первого объекта проверяется наличие такого же свойства второго объекта. В конце наоборот.
В середине сверяются значения этого свойства у двух объектов в случае их наличия. В зависимости от того, какое это свойство, свой обработчик. Если объект, то рекурсивно проверяем дальше, если функция, то на наличие определения и сравнение названия, ну и так далее.

Comment: Этот вариант рабочий но будте внимательны он не работает с датой

то есть если свойства дата отличается то он на них не реагирует

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = {};
var b = {};

a.prop1 = 2;
a.prop2 = { prop3: 2 };

b.prop1 = 2;
b.prop2 = { prop3: 3 };

console.log(_.isEqual(a, b)); // <- lodash
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Обычно я делаю так:

```
Object.keys({ ...first, ...second }).every(key => first[key] === second[key]);
```

Comment: Интересное решение, но не работает в случае вложенности:
`const first = {a: 3, b: 123, c: {d: 123}};


const second = { b: 123, c: {d: 123}, a: 3};



Object.keys({...first, ...second}).every(key => first[key] === second[key]); // false
`

Comment: рекурсия в помощь))